# How to connect computers to switch?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, switch

Me and my teacher came up with a problem that shutting down over 14+ PC's, updating them one by one takes tons of time and annoying to do.

We have switches on the second floor, computer class at third floor with over 14+ PC's and 1 main PC that teacher works on.

How can I and teacher connect computers to switch without Ethernet cable? Our goal is to get them all connected to switch and then, for example... use the command "shutdown now" on main PC and all other computers in computer class, over 14+ PC's will be shut down immediately.

One tip: We cannot use Ethernet cable to connect computers piece by piece to switch ports because the distance is too great between two floors.

Comment: You may want to clarify that your use of "switch" refers to the means to interrupt electricity or that it means a networking device used to connect multiple computers. I believe you mean the former, but it's a good idea to clarify that.

Comment: Yes. Something like network device that is used to connect multiple computers.

Comment: You are mixing two problems. For network connectivity if you can not use cables, then you have WiFi. After that you need some sort of control software so that you have "remote hands" on each computer. There are a lot of solutions for this.

Answer (score 2):

> One tip: We cannot use Ethernet cable to connect computers piece by piece to switch ports because the distance is too great between two floors.

Move one switch to the computer class.

(If there aren't any spare switches, well, buy a new one specifically for the computer class.)

If you *must* connecti to the 2nd floor – well, from your description it seems like the computer class *already* has at least one Ethernet cable coming in – which means the distance is not a problem. Are you really sure there's 100 meters between 2nd and 3rd floors?

(I've seen some "creative" wiring, such as the cable going outside through the window, *nine* floors down a wall, then back inside... Would not recommend, though.)

If the distance *is* a problem, run Ethernet over optical fiber – although that is probably three or four times more expensive than buying a switch, but still quite doable and the reach can be many kilometers.

You really can't do without some sort of cabling though – if the distance is too big for Ethernet, then it'll be too big for Wi-Fi and other wireless solutions as well. Though if by chance there's a coaxial antenna cable going between two floors, that could be used to carry Ethernet over MoCA, but I'm not sure of its limits.

Answer (score 1):

Put (at least) one switch on the third floor, or use several switches to keep cabling from the PC to the nearest switch short. Run cables along the corridors from switch to switch. Connect the main switch on the third floor with the switch on the second floor. Simple dumb switches are not expensive, buy as many as you need.

There's always a way to connect floors: Run the cable along the stairs, along some ventilation shaft or an unused chimney, through an unused water pipe, along the electrical cables, or even along the outside (normally not recommend, any thunderstorm can destroy your equipment) ... Talk to someone who knows the building well, and look at the plans, if there are any.

There are alternatives to connecting floors by ethernet (WLAN, powerline) but they are all inferior and won't give you the transfer speeds you need.